# Tiddlywiki - Does the wiki app support tiddler versioning, the ability to view older versions of tiddlers?

Tags: tiddlywiki

I was wondering if there is a way to store or view older versions of a tiddler and view, link, refer to them. Maybe there is a plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to tiddlywiki 5 (the version from tiddlywiki.com) there is no plugin for versioning. But it wouldn't be hard to set up a versioning system using the clone button and some tags. This has come up recently on the [google groups site](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiddlywiki) and if you watch/ask there someone will probably make something to do versioning of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming across this question 6+ years later, local revisions still haven't made it into the official core TiddlyMap.

There IS a plug that gets the job done, though: http://j.d.revisions.tiddlyspot.com/

Install that and a new revisions tab will appear under each tiddler's info area.  Revisions are numbered sequentially from most recent, with the option of "pinning" revisions you don't want to age out.

The magic is performed by replacing the default save / delete tiddler functions, instead cloning the original version of the tiddler whenever saving changes.  The delete tiddler function is also updated to remove any associated revisions if/when the original tiddler is deleted).